# How do I get bluemix logs to include stacktraces?

Tags: java, ibm-cloud, websphere-liberty

Our code simply uses java.util.logging to log info, errors etc. I can then view these logs in multiple ways:

1. cf logs command
2. bluemix web console (log aggregator)
3. kibana web ui
4. ssh and cat /home/vcap/logs/messages.log

If I log a message, it shows up everywhere. If I log a message and pass an exception parameter, the message shows up everywhere but the exception only shows up in /home/vcap/logs/messages.log. The exception and stacktrace do not show up in cf logs, bluemix console or kibana. Since the messages.log file has a finite size and is not persisted across re-stages, I can't always look in it to get the information I need.

So how can I can ensure the full log message including the exception is being fully logged?

Answer (score 0):

By default, messages.log will only contain messages that are written or captured by the logging component.  The FFDC logs (in the logs directory of each application) should contain full stack traces. See [1] and [2] for more details:

[1] https://console.bluemix.net/docs/runtimes/liberty/loggingAndTracing.html#logging_tracing

[2] https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.doc/ae/rwlp_logging.html

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately the logging component is not writing everything to message.log that I send to it. Example:
    sLogger.log(Level.WARNING, "hello", new ServletException("This is a caught exception."));
This will log "hello" but not the message or the stack from the exception. The stack is not written to ffdc either since it's a caught exception.

Comment: If I don't log the exception and instead let Liberty handle it, the exception is logged well in messages.log but each stacktrace line shows up as a different entry in Kibana (and the Logs web ui). This makes it very hard to find & read exceptions. I don't want to rely on ffdc files to get the stack since it means we can't just monitor 1 file plus they will be deleted if/when the box is re-staged. I was expecting Kibana to be the best place to read/store/retrieve logs but they're not formatted well and I just learned they are only retained for 7 days.

Comment: Have other people found the same results as me? Is there different behaviour using other log libraries (log4j, slf4gj etc). Are there better log syncs we can use?

Answer (score 0):

the following article provides information specific to logging & tracing:
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.doc/ae/rwlp_logging.html

Table 2 provides valid logging levels. Take a look at this table and use the appropriate log level to get the information you need in logs. hope this helps.